# Why are there two lists when using autocomplete on combobox in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, datagridview, combobox, autocomplete

I recently built a windows forms application using Visual Studio 2013 .Net 4.5 using VB.net. One of my users showed me this while using the app. In the datagridview, if they click the drop down button, then start typing, it overlays the autocomplete over the original dropdown. What am i doing wrong here?

```
Private Sub Data_CreateOrder_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles Data_CreateOrder.EditingControlShowing
   If Data_CreateOrder.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 AndAlso TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
        With DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
                .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
                .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
                .SelectAll()
                .BackColor = Color.White
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot]
[image: properties]

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing should be expected.  As a `ComboBox`, the full list of items will be visible (as seen in the background dropdown of your screenshot) because of:

```
.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
```

The overlaying list of items is visible to suggest appending items and is simply a narrowed down list based on the current user input. This list is showing because of:

```
.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
```

If you want the user to see a narrowed list of options related to their input, this behavior should be expected. If you don't want this additional dropdown to appear, remove the above line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you

```
Private Sub AdvancedDataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles AdvancedDataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
        Dim cbo As ComboBox

        If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then`enter code here`

            cbo = e.Control

            cbo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown

            cbo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

            '  cbo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
            cbo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems



        End If
    End Sub
```

abdelaziz sebrou